# Using Dask distributed scheduler

Tags: python, queue, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to setup a local dask cluster which adds tasks to the scheduler via `scheduler.submit()`. I like to record all transmitted task jobs to a python file for later replaying of the given tasks.

I've implemented this using subclassing and I'm looking for a better implementation for this. What technology is the scheduler using for enqueuing jobs in the scheduler? Is there a way to record this?